# Row of first cell with text, search from bottom

Tags: excel, row, match, lookup, bottom-up

If have texts in column A, with empty cells
In B20, I 'd like to get the row number of the first non empty cell above A20, without VBA.

I found some examples with "LOOKUP" function but I get "DIV/0" error. Perharps because I have text and not numbers in column A ?

Could you help me please ?

Comment: What formula did you have when using `lookup()`?

Comment: This works if I search a specific value ("Thomas") but not with "*" =LOOKUP(2,1/(A1:A4="*"),B1:B4). How can I get the first non empty cell please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

`=MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK($A20:$A1048576),0,0),0)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this give me the first empty cell from top to bottom. I 'd like to find the first non empty cell from bottom to top. In column A I have rows 1 to 5 with text, row 6 emtpy, rows 7 to 18 with text, row 19 and 20 empty, rows 21 to 30 with text. In B20, if I 'd like to get the text that is in A18 (first cell with text from bottom to top).